# Получение цвета пискселя из файла JPG и заполнение в массив

Tags: массивы, c++, visual-c++

Здарова всем! ;) Делаю систему столкновения по маске коллизии, надо получить цвета пискселя из файла JPG и заполнить их соответственно в массив. Прошу помочь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разбейте задачу на две преобразовать JPEG  в bmp и вторая - загрузка пикселей с bmp.  Это самый простой вариант.

Comment: Ну с первой задачей я справлюсь, а как насчёт второй?

Comment: Зависит от класса,который захотите использовать.  Но там с большой вероятностью будет метод getpixel(x,y)